# Capturing traceback from R when an RRuntimeError is raised

Tags: python-2.7, python-2.x, rpy2, traceback

A Python class executes R functions via rpy2, and I would like to be able to capture the traceback from R in the event that an R function generates an error.

The R code is legacy, so modifying it would be very risky; I would prefer to do something on the Python side.

Here's what the Python code looks like currently:

```
from rpy2.rinterface import RRuntimeError
from rpy2.robjects import DataFrame
from rpy2.robjects.packages import InstalledPackage

class RAdapter(BaseRAdapter):
    _module = None # type: InstalledPackage

    def call_raw(self, function_name, *args, **kwargs):
        # type: (str, tuple, dict) -> DataFrame
        """
        Invokes an R function and returns the result as a DataFrame.
        """
        try:
            return getattr(self._module, function_name)(*args, **kwargs)
        except RRuntimeError as e:
            # :todo: Capture traceback from R and attach to `e`.
            e.context = {'r_traceback': '???'}
            raise

    ...
```

How should I modify `call_raw` so that it captures the traceback from R in the event that the R function causes an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`traceback()` is the go-to function for generating error tracebacks in R.  Using `rpy2.robjects.r`, you can eval the `traceback()` function and store the result directly to a Python variable.

Note for rpy2 v2.8.x:  The result of `traceback()` is a pairlist, which [rpy2 can work with just fine](/a/40063135/), but there's [an issue that prevents `repr` from working correctly](https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/380/valueerror-when-getting-repr-of-a-pairlist).  To make the code easier to debug, it uses `unlist` to convert the pairlist into a list.

Be aware that `traceback()` also sends the traceback to stdout, and there is no way (that I know of) to avoid this, except to [temporarily] override `sys.stdout`.

Here's how `RAdapter.call_raw()` can capture the R traceback:

```
# If you are using rpy2 < 3.4.5 change the next line to:
# from rpy2.rinterface import RRuntimeError
from rpy2.rinterface_lib.embedded import RRuntimeError

from rpy2.robjects import DataFrame, r
from rpy2.robjects.packages import InstalledPackage

class RAdapter(BaseRAdapter):
    _module = None # type: InstalledPackage

    def call_raw(self, function_name, *args, **kwargs):
        # type: (str, *typing.Any, **typing.Any) -> DataFrame
        """
        Invokes an R function and returns the result as a DataFrame.
        """
        try:
            return getattr(self._module, function_name)(*args, **kwargs)
        except RRuntimeError as e:
            # Attempt to capture the traceback from R.
            try:
                e.context = {
                    # :kludge: Have to use `unlist` because `traceback`
                    #   returns a pairlist, which rpy2 doesn't know how
                    #   to repr.
                    'r_traceback': '\n'.join(r('unlist(traceback())'))
                }
            except Exception as traceback_exc:
                e.context = {
                    'r_traceback':
                        '(an error occurred while getting traceback from R)',

                    'r_traceback_err':  traceback_exc,
                }

            raise

    ...
```

Tested with `rpy2==2.8.3`.

Comment: I'll just add you're missing an import:
`from rpy2.robjects import r`

Also, in rpy2==3.4.5 the run time error is imported as
`from rpy2.rinterface_lib.embedded import RRuntimeError`

Comment: @IyarLin good catch, thanks!  Incorporated into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`rpy2` can handle R pairlists (mostly) fine. However, their representation (method `__repr__`) appears to have a bug: the general `__repr__` for R vectors is using slices, and slices are not available for pairlist objects.

```
>>> from rpy2.robjects import baseenv
>>> opts = baseenv['.Options']
>>> opts.typeof # this is a pairlist
2
>>> print(opts) # working
...
>>> str(opts) # working
>>> opts.items() # working
>>> repr(opts) # ValueError: Cannot handle R type 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!  I have logged [an issue on the rpy2 repo](https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/380/valueerror-when-getting-repr-of-a-pairlist) for follow-up.